# How to use function variables in another function without passing as parameter in Python?

Tags: python

In the below function, how to use the parameters of pim function within chat and chat1 without passing them as parameters?

base.py:

```
def pim(mode, tag, population_file, variable_file, aggregation, user, 
        passw, email, working_schema, output_schema):

    print mode
    print tag
    print population_file
    print variable_file
    print aggregation
    print user
    print passw
    print email
    print working_schema
    print output_schema


    chat()
    chat1()
```

I tried using `from base import *` in to chat.py (where `chat()` is created), but it is not recognizing. I would like to know if there is a way to access the parameters without passing them as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like that the reason you avoid to pass the parameters is that there is a **bloody long** parameter list.

You can actually change the function `pim` to the followings:

```
def pim(*args):
    print(args[0])
    print(args[1])
    print(args[2])
    print(args[3])
    chat(args)
    chat1(args)
# You can call this function by 
pim(mode,tag,population_file,variable_file,aggregation,user,passw,email,working_schema,output_schema)
```

or you can use optional arguments format as follows:

```
def pim(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['mode'])
    print(kwargs['tag'])
    print(kwargs['population_file'])
    print(kwargs['variable_file'])
    chat(kwargs)
    chat1(kwargs)
# and you can call your function by
pim(mode='1', tag='2', 'population_file'=3, 'variable_file'=4)
```

or you can use the `global` keyword to make the parameters global available, however, this solution is not recommended.